# How to replace all values in a column with another value?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Suppose I have a data frame `df` with two columns:

```
id category 
A  1
B  4
C  3
D  1
```

I want to replace the numbers in category with the following: `1 = "A", 2 = "B", 3 = "C", 4 = "D".`

I.e. the output should be

```
id category 
A  A
B  D
C  C
D  A
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I propose three methods to achieve your goal.

#### Base R

If you have a vector of values for conversion, you can use `match` to find the index of the vector to replace the `category` column.

```
vec <- c("1" = "A", "2" = "B", "3" = "C", "4" = "D")

df$category <- vec[match(df$category, names(vec))]
```

#### dplyr

Use a `case_when` statement to match the values in `category`, and assign new strings to it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(category = case_when(category == 1 ~ "A",
                                   category == 2 ~ "B",
                                   category == 3 ~ "C",
                                   category == 4 ~ "D",
                                   TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

##### left_join from dplyr

Or if you have a dataframe with two columns specifying values for conversion, you can `left_join` them. Here, the dataframe for conversion is created by `enframe`.

```
left_join(df, enframe(vec), by = c("category" = "name")) %>% select(-value)
```

#### Output

```
  id category
1  A        A
2  B        D
3  C        C
4  D        A
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), category = c("A", 
"D", "C", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. How does ```TRUE ~ NA_character_``` handle missing values? Didn't find an explanation in the [reference manual](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html)

Comment: @Simone You might want to take a look at the manual for [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) instead of `mutate`. The `TRUE` statement catches any conditions that is not met in the other conditions in `case_when`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(category = LETTERS[category])

#>   id category
#> 1  A        A
#> 2  B        D
#> 3  C        C
#> 4  D        A
```